# get thumbnail of online video as widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How to get first frame of online video on flutter?
I try use https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail_imageview but their backend not working, so library do not return thumbnail. Any idea how to do it without downloading whole video from web?
For me it is important to run this on platform iOS/Android/Web